# Python - Multiple URL - Append/Extend to Single Dataframe

Tags: python, json

I'm new to Python, but I've successfully connected to an api and upserted the data to our SQL database. However, I need to run the same process, with multiple URL's with identical data being returned. I'd like to build a single dataframe out of it, and then utilize all my existing upsert code.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
URLs = ["https://www.url1.com/fall","https://www.url1.com/spring"]

data_results = []

payload={}
headers = {
'apikey': apikey
}

for url in URLs:
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        print(f"Error {url}")

        continue

    data_results.extend(resp)
    data_results = resp.json(strict=False)
```

I've also changed .extend to .append

Then I wanted to build the dataframe from data_results

I get the output of the 2nd url only.

Am I missing something easy?

Comment: You are overwriting `data_results` on the last line

Comment: When I removed that lines, I get: Shape of passed values is (1913, 1), indices imply (1913, 10)  -- so it would imply both URL responses are on a single column? This is when it hits the dataframe creation.

Comment: Maybe you want to `data_results.append(resp.json(strict=False))` ?

Comment: That appears to get farther - 10 columns passed, passed data had 839 columns (there are 839 rows in the 2nd url, 840 in the first)

Comment: changing append to extend gets a 2nd url output only

Comment: first put code with correct indentations because they can change everything.

Comment: you should check what you get from server. Maybe you get different data then you expect. Maybe it can't send the same number of data in requests.

Answer (score 0):

It was a combination of both of you!

```
for url in URLs:
   resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
   if resp.status_code != 200:
      print(f"Error {url}")
      continue
   data_results.extend(resp.json(strict=False))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).